# How to move all nodes with same name and appending after firstchild

Tags: xml, powershell, xml-parsing

I have 2 XML files and I'm importing nodes from File2 to File1. File2 has elements that are named the same, so when I use selectNodes using the node name, all nodes do not move over, and instead, I get this error:

`Exception calling "InsertAfter" with "2" argument(s): "The reference node is not a child of this node."`

When I select each node with the same name individualy by using `SelectSingleNode("//*[contains(@id,'1')]")`, it works. Is there a way I can move all of them in one go? I imagine I might need to look at this more in a loop perspective instead of going at it individually.

```
$file1 = [xml](Get-Content "file1.xml")
$file2 = [xml](Get-Content "file2.xml")

$testNodes= $file2.root.test
$contentAdd= $file1.root

$ammendOutcome = $file1.ImportNode($testNodes, $TRUE)
$contentAdd.InsertAfter($ammendOutcome, $contentAdd.FirstChild)
```

Example File 1:

```
<root>
    <child1 />
</root>
```

Example File2:

```
<root>
    <test id="1" />
    <test id ="2" />
    <test id ="3">
        <update score="1" />
    </test>
</root>
```

Expecting:

```
<root>
    <child1 />
    <test id="1" />
    <test id ="2" />
    <test id ="3">
        <update score="1" />
    </test>
</root>
```

Answer (score 0):

`ImportNode()` (note the lack of `s` at the end of the method name) expects a *single* node, not a list of nodes like you have in `$testNodes`. Also, if you want the nodes in that order in the output you need to insert them in reverse order when using `InsertAfter()`.

```
$testNodes | Sort-Object id | ForEach-Object {
    $ammendOutcome = $file1.ImportNode($_, $true)
    $contentAdd.InsertAfter($ammendOutcome, $contentAdd.FirstChild)
}
```